# Java: execution of command gets stuck

Tags: java, tomcat

I have an installer. The installer calls a method `doSetup()` to do the following:

1. Set CATALINA_HOME variable with `setx` command (to permanently store the variable in system variables).
2. Set CATALINA_HOME variable with `set` command (to use CATALINA_HOME for current `cmd` session).
3. Install tomcat as a service.
4. Update service name.

Here is the implementation of `doSetup()`

```java
private void doSetup() {
    String installPath = InstallData.getInstance().getInstallPath();
    String setConfigCommon = installPath + "\\EmbeddedTomcat\\bin\\tomcat8 //US//Tomcat8";
    String catalinaHome = installPath + "\\EmbeddedTomcat";
    catalinaHome = "\"" + catalinaHome + "\"";
    String setxCatalinaHome = "setx CATALINA_HOME " + catalinaHome + " /m";
    String setCatalinaHome = "cmd.exe /c set CATALINA_HOME=" + catalinaHome;
    String installService = installPath+"\\EmbeddedTomcat\\bin\\service.bat install";
    String setName = " --DisplayName=\"MyService\"";
    if(installPath.endsWith("\\")) {
        installPath = installPath.substring(0, installPath.length()-1);
    }
    Exception exception =  null;
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
    try {
        log.info("SETX : CATALINA_HOME");
        InstallHelper.executeCommand(setxCatalinaHome);
        log.info("SETX : DONE");
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(pw);
        exception = e;
        log.info(e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        log.info("SET : CATALINA_HOME");
        InstallHelper.executeCommand(setCatalinaHome);
        log.info("SET : DONE");
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(pw);
        exception = e;
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        log.info("INSTALL : Service");
        InstallHelper.executeCommand(installService);
        log.info("INSTALL : DONE");
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(pw);
        exception = e;
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        log.info("UPDATE: Service name");
        InstallHelper.executeCommand(setConfigCommon + setName);
        log.info("UPDATE: DONE");
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(pw);
        exception = e;
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And here is the implementation of `executeCommand()`

```java
public static String executeCommand(String commandName) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
    try {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandName);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
            result.append("\n");
        }
        input.close();
        return result.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace(pw);
        log.error(sw.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I check the log I see that up to step 3 (of the 4 steps mentioned above) is getting executed and then it gets stuck while updating the service. This is what the log file looks like:

```
[18-10-22 15:38:22] INFO  panels.InstallationSurvey - Check log is writable, SUCCESS
[18-10-22 15:38:29] DEBUG panels.InstallationSurvey - Windows PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
[18-10-22 15:38:29] INFO  panels.InstallationSurvey - 64-Bit Windows found!
[18-10-22 15:38:29] INFO  panels.InstallationSurvey - <B>COMPLETE</B>
[18-10-22 15:38:30] INFO  panels.PreInstallPanel - <b>COMPLETE</b>
[18-10-22 15:38:38] INFO  panels.PortCheckPanel - Port Test SUCCESS
[18-10-22 15:39:25] INFO  panels.WindowsServicePanel - SETX : CATALINA_HOME
[18-10-22 15:39:25] INFO  panels.WindowsServicePanel - SETX : DONE
[18-10-22 15:39:25] INFO  panels.WindowsServicePanel - SET : CATALINA_HOME
[18-10-22 15:39:26] INFO  panels.WindowsServicePanel - SET : DONE
[18-10-22 15:39:26] INFO  panels.WindowsServicePanel - INSTALL : Service
[18-10-22 15:39:26] INFO  panels.WindowsServicePanel - INSTALL : DONE
[18-10-22 15:39:27] INFO  panels.WindowsServicePanel - UPDATE: Service name
```

Interesting fact : I have run the installer many times. Sometimes it doesn't get stuck and sometimes it gets stuck as described.

Do I need to add/remove any code to get rid of this weird behavior? Or any suggestions what to do?

Comment: ```Runtime.exec``` should really be seen as legacy. You should be using ```ProcessBuilder``` and processing stderr properly, along with stdout

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes it doesn't get stuck

Probably because you are not waiting for the command to terminate. Refer to method `waitFor` in class `java.lang.Process`. Then you can also remove the calls to [static] method `sleep` (of class `Thread`).

`Runtime` is not a Windows command prompt. You should rather use class `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`.

Your code should look similar to the following:
(Note the below are only excerpts in order to illustrate what changes you need to make.)

In method `doSetup`

```java
private void doSetup() {
    String installPath = InstallData.getInstance().getInstallPath();
    String catalinaHome = installPath + "\\EmbeddedTomcat";
    catalinaHome = "\"" + catalinaHome + "\"";
    List<String> setxCatalinaHome = List.of("setx", "CATALINA_HOME", catalinaHome, "/m");
    InstallHelper.executeCommand(setxCatalinaHome);
}
```

Method `executeCommand`

```java
public static String executeCommand(List<String> commandName) {
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        String line;
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commandName);
        Process p = pb.start();
        BufferedReader input = p.inputReader();
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
            result.append("\n");
        }
        int status = p.waitFor();
        if (status != 0) {
            // Command failed. What to do?
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception err) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        err.printStackTrace(pw);
        log.error(sw.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

An executed command may fail. You need to handle that situation. Also, method `inputReader` was added in JDK 17. If you are using a lower JDK version, the alternative is `getInputStream` (which you are currently using). By the way, closing the `BufferedReader` will also try to close the wrapped `InputStream` but you didn't create that `InputStream` and therefore you should not close it, so I suggest removing the code that closes the `BufferedReader`.

Also note that you may need to explicitly set the working directory before executing a command. Refer to method [directory](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory(java.io.File)) in class `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: I made the changes. But now all the commands are skipped. Here is the log file

[19-10-22 16:19:45] INFO  panels.InstallationSurvey - Check log is writable, SUCCESS
[19-10-22 16:20:11] DEBUG panels.InstallationSurvey - Windows PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
[19-10-22 16:20:11] INFO  panels.InstallationSurvey - 64-Bit Windows found!
[19-10-22 16:20:11] INFO  panels.InstallationSurvey - <B>COMPLETE</B>
[19-10-22 16:20:12] INFO  panels.PreInstallPanel - <b>COMPLETE</b>
[19-10-22 16:20:20] INFO  panels.PortCheckPanel - Port Test SUCCESS

Comment: Here is the [link](https://pastebin.com/vuqQuxe2) to log file and updated code.

Comment: @MahmudMridul Try writing a test program that simply executes a single command. Then run that program, separately, for each, individual command and check that each, individual command executes successfully when executed by itself. Then write a test program that executes two commands, one after the other. Slowly add more commands. You need to understand how the code works, not just copy paste it in the belief that it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Tried it. the `line = input.readLine()` here `line` is `null`. And `status` is 1. I assume `line` should not be null here.

Comment: UPDATE : I went through the documentation and added `pb.redirectErrorStream(true);` before `pb.start()`. Now  `line = ERROR: Access to the registry path is denied.`